# Prevent flask app's development server from unwanted reloads

Tags: python, flask, reload, web-development-server

I was running a flask app at http://127.0.0.1:7000/ with the command `py main.py`. In my file, the last line is `app.run(debug=True, port=7000)`. I have declared the `app = Flask(__name__)`. I need the server to restart each time. But the server reloads for unwanted files, and does not allow me to view the page even! The log is:

```
F:\Github SPRINGREEN\web-app>py main.py
 * Serving Flask app "main" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with windowsapi reloader
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 140-651-644
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:7000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pip\\_vendor\\toml\\encoder.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pip\\_vendor\\toml\\ordered.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pip\\_vendor\\toml\\tz.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pip\\_vendor\\toml\\__init__.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pip\\_vendor\\urllib3\\connection.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pip\\_vendor\\urllib3\\connectionpool.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pip\\_vendor\\urllib3\\exceptions.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pip\\_vendor\\urllib3\\fields.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pip\\_vendor\\urllib3\\filepost.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pip\\_vendor\\urllib3\\poolmanager.py', reloading
 * Restarting with windowsapi reloader
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 140-651-644
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:7000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth__tkinter.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\__init__.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\lib\\modulegraph\\find_modules.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\lib\\modulegraph\\modulegraph.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\lib\\modulegraph\\util.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\lib\\modulegraph\\zipio.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\lib\\modulegraph\\_compat.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\lib\\modulegraph\\__init__.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\lib\\modulegraph\\__main__.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\utils\\cliutils\\archive_viewer.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\utils\\cliutils\\bindepend.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\utils\\cliutils\\grab_version.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\utils\\cliutils\\makespec.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\utils\\cliutils\\set_version.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\utils\\cliutils\\__init__.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\utils\\hooks\\django.py', reloading
 * Restarting with windowsapi reloader
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 140-651-644
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:7000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrogram\\methods\\advanced\\resolve_peer.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrogram\\methods\\advanced\\save_file.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrogram\\methods\\advanced\\send.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrogram\\methods\\advanced\\__init__.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrogram\\methods\\auth\\accept_terms_of_service.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrogram\\methods\\auth\\check_password.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrogram\\methods\\auth\\connect.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrogram\\methods\\auth\\disconnect.py', reloading
 * Restarting with windowsapi reloader
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 140-651-644
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:7000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrogram\\methods\\chats\\leave_chat.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrogram\\methods\\chats\\mark_chat_unread.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrogram\\methods\\chats\\pin_chat_message.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrogram\\methods\\chats\\promote_chat_member.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrogram\\methods\\chats\\restrict_chat_member.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrogram\\methods\\chats\\set_administrator_title.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrogram\\methods\\chats\\set_chat_description.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrogram\\methods\\chats\\set_chat_permissions.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrogram\\methods\\chats\\set_chat_photo.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrogram\\methods\\chats\\set_chat_title.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrogram\\methods\\chats\\set_slow_mode.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrogram\\methods\\chats\\unarchive_chats.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrogram\\methods\\chats\\unban_chat_member.py', reloading
```

but, I am working with the file at dir: `F:\flask-app\app-1\main.py`, with the folder `F:\flask-app\app-1` folder open in my VS code. I just want the flask to reload when I make changes in the files present in the folder: `F:\flask-app\app-1` and not any other files! Is there any way? Some specifications:

```
C:\User\new>python -V
Python 3.9.1

C:\User\new>python -m flask --version
Python 3.9.1
Flask 1.1.2
Werkzeug 1.0.1

C:\User\new>cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.985]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

I am using Windows 32-bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is somewhat odd behaviour but I think it might be because you are using the global python interpreter. I would recommend creating a virtual environment like
`python -m venv env`
and then
`.\env\Scripts\activate`

and then install all the packages there and try running flask again.

Comment: I did not expect the VENV will help me! Thanks that worked well for me.

Comment: This was even somewhat unexpected for me too. I don't use windows but I assumed it might be the case. Anyway, glad it worked.

Comment: watchdog on Windows can't differentiate between read access and write access, as written. This makes it restart in surprising places - e.g. I have a utility script in my web application, and running it while the Flask dev server is running will make it restart (Detected change in testtool.py) when the Last Read metadata is updated.
There is some discussion here: https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog/issues/260